# entity bean with uncheck or unsafe operation

Tags: java, ejb

I am learning Entity Bean and I get this error when I am doing my lab. I chose to create a Session Bean for Entity class (for Entity `Product`). This file is automatically created by NetBeans. But it informs that `ProductsFacade.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`

Here is the code:

```
@Stateless
public class ProductsFacade implements ProductsFacadeRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "NhungBHSE02082_SE0606_AdvJava_Lab10_11-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(Products products) {
        em.persist(products);
    }

    public void edit(Products products) {
        em.merge(products);`enter code here`
    }

    public void remove(Products products) {
        em.remove(em.merge(products));
    }

    public Products find(Object id) {
        return em.find(Products.class, id);
    }

    public List<Products> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("select object(o) from Products as o").getResultList();
    }

    public List<Products> findRange(int[] range) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select object(o) from Products as o");
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        return ((Long) em.createQuery("select count(o) from Products as o").getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the following init method to the class. The web container initializes the servlet by calling its init method. This occurs only once, after the servlet is loaded and before it begins servicing requests.                                                        public void init() throws ServletException {  and place the methods to find objects inside this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the warning is due to the following methods:

```
public List<Products> findAll() {
    return em.createQuery("select object(o) from Products as o").getResultList();
}

public List<Products> findRange(int[] range) {
    ...
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

What happens internally is `query.getResultList()` returns generic `List`. Each Object in the List is of type `Products`. You know that, but compiler doesn't know. The type can be determined only at runtime. So the compiler shows the warning *uncheck or unsafe operation*. You can safely ignore this warning.

If you are really worried, then you can add the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to these two methods for the warning to disappear.

Comment: It returns `List` not `List<Object>`. If it was than it would never compile: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast.

Comment: Thank you very much! The warning disappreared. I have just submited my lab.

Comment: @BeeBee u're welcome :) but please **accept** answers. If you don't know what that means then this post is for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

The [`Query.getResultList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) returns `List` which is non-generic, and is implicitly being casted to `List<Products>`. Now since, `List` is non-generic, the compiler doesn't have information necessary to make sure that it is actually the list of `Products`s. That's why the compiler show the warning.

Even though the compiler doesn't know, but you know that it's actually always going to be a list of `Products`s, which guarantees that the cast will never fail at runtime, so you can decorate your method with annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` here

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Products> findAll() {
    return em.createQuery("select object(o) from Products as o").getResultList();
}
```

That will take the warning away.

Also: Other way is to use [`TypedQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html).